# Room fallbackToDestructiveMigration

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I get acquainted with Room and try to assemble a small project by reading the database from the **ASSETS folder**. Faced such a question: When one version of the database is thrown, it throws an exception and asks to add MIGRATION. It’s enough for me to simply rewrite the database from assets when raising the version. There is a **`fallbackToDestructiveMigration ()`** method in the docks for this purpose. But when I specify it in the builder, in fact my database is overwritten every time the application starts. What I need is for the database to be rewritten from assets only when the application version is raised. and I don’t understand how to achieve this behavior. I would be grateful for your help.

This is how I do everything:

This is the simplest example.

DAO:

```
 @Dao
NameDao
@Insert(entity = Name.class, onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insertMe(Name name);
```

Database

```
    @Database(version = 2, entities = [Name::class])
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun nameDao(): NameDao
}
```

POJO Entity

```
@Entity(tableName = "tips_of_the_day")
data class Name(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    var name: String?
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "_id")
    var id: Int = 0
}
```

Application class

```
class App : Application() {
private lateinit var appDatabase: AppDatabase


override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    appDatabase = getAppDatabase()
}

 fun getAppDatabase(): AppDatabase {

    return Room.databaseBuilder(
        this,
        AppDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME
    )
        .createFromAsset("database/tips_of_the_day.db")
        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
        .allowMainThreadQueries()
        .build().also { appDatabase = it }

}

companion object {
    private const val DATABASE_NAME = "tips_of_the_day.db"
}
}
```

AND MY ACTIVITY

```
val db: AppDatabase = (application as App).getAppDatabase()
    val dataBase = db.nameDao()


    textView.setOnClickListener(){
        val name: Name = Name( "Anton")
        dataBase.insertMe(name)
        val tableSize: Int = dataBase.all.size
        toast("db size  : $tableSize")
        Log.d("TAG" , "db size  : $tableSize")
    }
```

It turns out that the code works until the application is restarted and then the database is overwritten by default and becomes new (

I did not want this behavior. I need to save the database until the version is up. How to achieve this?

Comment: Just to clarify - when you change the number of version in Database class to next number ("2" for example), do you change the attached database from assets folder to updated version 2 as well?

Comment: @sergiytikhonov even if I do not change the version number, and do not touch the database, my application overwrites the data at each start.

Comment: I did not want this behavior. I need to save the database until the version is up. How to achieve this?

Comment: @Романыч how did you solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I know it may seemed like a dirty way to solve your problem, but you can manage migrate-or-not issue manually:

```
fun getAppDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
        // is migration really needed?
        val db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY)
        val needToMigrate = db.version < dbVersion // your actual version, could be constant
        db.close()
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME)
            .allowMainThreadQueries().apply {
            if (needToMigrate) this.createFromAsset(DATABASE_DIR)
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
        }.build()
    }
```